# multivariable derivative in R

Tags: r, derivative

Could somebody help me with simple mathematic operation in R?

All I want to do is:

I have a function

```
f <-(a1*x1+a2*x2+…+an*xn~x1&…&xn)
```

and derivative of this function

```
df<-D(f(x1…xn)~…)
```

What I need to fill in the '…' gap to obtain a result of multivariable derivative?
The problem is that I can't address to value of vector c(x1,x2,x3…xn)

As a result I need to write a "for"-cycle on each step of which it gets me a result of derivative

Comment: Can please show what `f <-(a1*x1+a2*x2+…+an*xn~x1&…&xn)` actually is in code? And can you clarify what you are taking the derivative with respect to (e.g. all partial derivatives {`df/dx1, ... , df/dxn`}, etc...)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have a fixed `n`? If so, you can use `parse` to transform a string in an expression:

```
x = c('x1','x2','x3')
a = c('a1','a2','a3')
expr=parse(text=paste(paste(x, a, sep="*"), collapse="+"))

#> sapply(x, function(u) D(expr,u))
#$x1
#a1

#$x2
#a2

#$x3
#a3
```